# USB HDD not visible in nautilus/nemo

Tags: gnome, usb, nautilus

The HDD is visible in the 'disks' utility. I can mount the one and only partition on that drive using `mount`. gvfs-mount Recognizes the disk:

```
$ gvfs-mount --list
...
Drive(2): 750 GB Hard Disk
Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
```

dmesg looks like this:

```
[25081.614627] usb 2-6: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
[25081.747814] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=a93a
[25081.747826] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[25081.747834] usb 2-6: Product: Portable HDD SH93
[25081.747840] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: ADATA
[25081.747846] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: 000000000078
[25081.748425] scsi15 : usb-storage 2-6:1.0
[25082.744264] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ADATA    HDD SH93              PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[25082.746361] sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[25082.749729] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/698 GiB)
[25082.751350] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[25082.751365] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[25082.751826] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[25082.751834] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[25082.754559] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[25082.754561] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[25082.783022]  sdc: sdc1
[25082.785984] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[25082.785995] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[25082.786002] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

The disk isn't visible in nautilus' "Devices" category. Other USB disks are visible and I can mount them with nautilus. That particular drive used to work with nautilus two months ago.

The only partition on that disk is formatted with vfat. I tried rebooting and it hasn't helped.

Edit: the drive is also invisible in dolphin, so there seems to be some underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a bit late but for others....

You can probably look up in the `udisks2.rules` in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules` and remove anything or all which comes after

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Devices which should not be display in the user interface
```

as your disk probably triggers one of those conditions. Alternatively, try removing some parts at a time.